# Bubblesort with LinkedList

Tags: linked-list

I'm having trouble with my bubblesort. It's looping through one occurrence before ending. It takes in an input file with various names and ages and sorts them. So far it's printing out:

```
Stella is 11 years old.
Fred is 88 years old.
George is 22 years old.
Violet is 33 years old.
Rose is 77 years old.
Bob is 66 years old.
Lena is 55 years old.
Billy is 44 years old.
Nellie is 99 years old.
```

When i want it to print out:

```
Stella is 11 years old.
George is 22 years old.
Violet is 33 years old.
Billy is 44 years old.
Lena is 55 years old.
Bob is 66 years old.
Rose is 77 years old.
Fred is 88 years old.
Nellie is 99 years old.
```

Current code:

```
  public void bubbleSort()
  { 
  PersonNode previous = head;
  PersonNode current = head.getNext();
  boolean swap = true;
  int j = 0;

  while(swap)
  {
     swap = false;

     while(previous != null)
     {           
        if(previous.getNext() != null && previous.getAge() > previous.getNext().getAge())
        {
           String tempName = previous.getName();
           Integer tempAge = previous.getAge();
           current = previous.getNext();
           previous.setName(current.getName());
           previous.setAge(current.getAge());
           current.setName(tempName);
           current.setAge(tempAge);
           swap = true;
        }
     previous = previous.getNext();
     }

  }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The code only "bubbles" one value, you will need to repeat the process from the start until no more swaps happen. It's a one-line change.

```
   public void bubbleSort()
{ 
  PersonNode previous = head;
  PersonNode current = head.getNext();
  boolean swap = true;

  while(swap)
  {
     swap = false;
     previous = head; /* restart */
     while(previous != null)
     {           
        if(previous.getNext() != null && previous.getAge() > previous.getNext().getAge())
        {
           String tempName = previous.getName();
           Integer tempAge = previous.getAge();
           current = previous.getNext();
           previous.setName(current.getName());
           previous.setAge(current.getAge());
           current.setName(tempName);
           current.setAge(tempAge);
           swap = true;
        }
     previous = previous.getNext();
     }

  }
```